# Linkedlist & hashmap _duplicates removal

Tags: java, linked-list, hash-map

I have implemented a LinkedList removal fo duplicates class by using HashMap.

Looking forward to your reviews.

Thanks.

```
package test;

import main.algorithms.LinkedListRemoveDuplicates;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LinkedListRemoveDuplicatesTest {

    LinkedListRemoveDuplicates linkedListRemoveDuplicates;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        linkedListRemoveDuplicates = new LinkedListRemoveDuplicates();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemoveDuplicates(){

        linkedListRemoveDuplicates.addBack(5);
        linkedListRemoveDuplicates.addBack(5);
        linkedListRemoveDuplicates.addBack(5);
        linkedListRemoveDuplicates.addBack(5);
        linkedListRemoveDuplicates.addBack(5);

        Assert.assertEquals(5, linkedListRemoveDuplicates.size());

        linkedListRemoveDuplicates.removeDuplicates();

        Assert.assertEquals(1, linkedListRemoveDuplicates.size());

    }
}


package main.algorithms;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class LinkedListRemoveDuplicates {

    Node head;

    int size;

    public void removeDuplicates() {

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> duplicatesList = new HashMap<>();

        Node currentNode = head;

        if(size==1){
            return;
        }
        //  2 1 3 1 2
        while(currentNode != null ){

            if(!duplicatesList.containsKey(currentNode.value)){
                duplicatesList.put(currentNode.value,1);
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            continue;
        }

        size = duplicatesList.size();
    }

    class Node{
        int value;
        Node next;
        public Node(int value){
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public void addBack(int i) {

        Node newNode = new Node(i);
        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
        }else{
            Node currentNode = head;
            while(currentNode.next != null){
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            currentNode.next = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the duplicates. It counts the unique elements.